# Self-Referential Has Many Through with Custom Foreign Keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model and a relationship table called ParentsChildren.

I'm trying to create two relationships on the User model so that `User#children` returns all of a users children and `User#parents` returns all of a users parents.

I've managed to get this working before, but I'm doing something wrong right this time, and I'm not sure what it is exactly.

```
class ParentsChildren < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'parents_children'
  belongs_to :parent_user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :child_user, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  has_many :parent_relationships, class_name: 'ParentsChildren', foreign_key: :parent_user_id
  has_many :child_relationships, class_name: 'ParentsChildren', foreign_key: :child_user_id

  has_many :children, through: :parent_relationships, class_name: 'User', source: :child_user
  has_many :parents, through: :child_relationships, class_name: 'User', source: :parent_user
end

# => uninitialized constant ParentsChildren::ChildUser
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The key was to drop 'User' as the class name for `has_many :parents` and `has_many :users`. It's inferred through the given sources.

```
class User
  has_many :parent_relationships, foreign_key: :child_user_id,
           class_name: 'ParentsChildren'
  has_many :children, through: :parent_relationships,
           source: :parent_user
  has_many :child_relationships, foreign_key: :parent_user_id,
           class_name: 'ParentsChildren'
  has_many :parents, through: :child_relationships,
           source: :child_user
end
```